# Google Maps + Divi + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I created a google maps API key and have it setup in Divi for WordPress.  However, whenever it loads - it's still showing that the map is in development mode, and in the java-script console I get the following:

`You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors js:39:424`

I'm confused why this message keeps coming up - as it's a brand new key that was just generated.

Comment: Were you getting that error message before you generated a new code? Because it could simply be that the map code is cached and still using the old API key?

Comment: Yeah - error message came up before the new code .. and it's been 24+ hours and still getting that message.  I also inspected the source code to make sure the new key was showing up there.

Comment: Did you enable Billing account? It is mandatory in order to use Google Maps Platform.

Comment: That was the issue.  I was unaware of that requirement with their new changes.